# How can I use xcode without having administrator privileges on a mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

My school has macs available in the library. I would like to learn how to develop iOS apps, but I cannot install xcode on the school's computers without administrative privileges. Is it possible to use a friends mac to install xcode on an external drive and bring it with me to school? If not, is there some other workaround besides getting the school admins to install it on a single mac for me? I'm afraid that if they install it on one computer it might not always be available when I want to use it. I also cannot afford to buy even the least expensive mac right now, so I am not sure how I can pursue my interests :(

Answer (score 2):

I know the Intel-based Macs (not sure about other models) running os X 10.7 upwards allow you to boot from external disk. If you make a complete installation, you can boot from that disk but it has to be bootable.
Just restart the computer and hold down "option" key when you hear the chime sound. Select the disk and and it should work fine.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It is not possible. You need to make a formal request to system admin to help you install "development tools" like Xcode, and most of the times they agree. If that does not work, ask a professor to make that request for you.